# Looking for web mail where entire session is SSL

Tags: email, ssl

I am looking for a web-UI email service where the entire session is SSL (encrypted). Gmail and Yahoo Mail are both web applications but SSL is only used for the login page, the rest of the session (including emails) are in the clear. I am willing to pay for such a service. It would of course have to have all the latest email features (search, folders, contacts, etc) and be reliable.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/25658/gmail-and-ssl-encryption-how-much-is-encrypted for more on encryption with webmail services.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can force Gmail to use SSL the entire time. Scroll down to "[Browser connection](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=mail&answer=74765)" on the first page of Settings, and check the "Always use HTTPS" option. And Done :D

Edit 4/29/2014: This is now enabled by the default but can be turned off. Also, Google Apps admins can allow or disallow the option to turn it off in Google's cpanel.

Comment: You should probably mention that this is for Gmail. I don't know if it is the same for Yahoo.

Comment: "You can force gmail to use SSL"
I think i did...
pretty sure you can with yahoo, if your willing to pay.

Answer (score 7):

GMail does SSL. Go to https://gmail.com instead of http://gmail.com

Comment: Correct. The Gmail setting "Browser connection: Always use https/Don't always use https" just enforces HTTPS, in case you forget to type `https://` yourself. So, to use HTTPS one does not need that setting per se.